# nginx: Serve both domain.com and www.domain.com

Tags: nginx, configuration, http

I currently have an nginx server which can be accessed by typing in domain.com both by HTTP and HTTPS. However when I attempt to connect by typing www.domain.com instead it seems that the connection will hang and Firefox reports "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.."

Here is my current server_name config:

```
server_name localhost www.example.com example.com;
```

The nginx documentation seems to suggest that this should work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do those two domains both resolve to the same IP address?

Answer (score 4):

This

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;    
    }
```

will redirect example.com to www.example.com, and this

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/example.com;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
```

will serve www.example.com.

You can do the same for https but it's unlikely that anyone will laboriously enter https:// and the non-cannonical address, so

```
server {
    listen  443;
    server_name www.example.com;


    ssl  on;
    ssl_certificate  /etc/ssl/private/www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/www.example.com.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!ADH:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;


    location / {
        root   /var/www/example.com;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
```

should suffice.

Comment: Please don't place `root` inside `location /`. This is a very common [nginx misconfiguration](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls).